# Robot Framework with Excel Library erroring: "local variable 'my_sheet_index' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, excel, robotframework

I have an issue with my ExcelLibrary proof of concept. When I try to save some data into new Excel file it returns an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_sheet_index' referenced before assignment` on `Put Number To Cell   sheetname=${mySheetName}    column=1    row=1    value=90`

Do you know what can I do to prevent getting that please? Here is my easy test file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             ExcelLibrary
Library             Collections

*** Variables ***
${Excel_File_Path}   C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\
${mySheetName}         UserImport

*** Test Cases ***
Excel Test
    Lubos Test

*** Keywords ***
Lubos Test
    Create Excel Workbook    newsheetname=${mySheetName}
    Put Number To Cell   sheetname=${mySheetName}    column=1    row=1    value=90
    Save Excel Current Directory    filename=MyNewExcel.xls
```

Comment: Ive managed to get around that error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_sheet_index' referenced before assignment` but Im now stumped with a `IndexError: list index out of range` when adding a number... I can give you my current code if you like to get around the first error but Im still trying to get around this second issue :(

Comment: Feel free to share @Goralight

Answer (score 2):

```
*** Settings ***
Library             ExcelLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Path}   C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\
${name}    Test.xls

*** Test Cases ***
Excel Test
    Create

*** Keywords ***
Create
    Create Excel Workbook    ${name}
    Open Excel    ${path}${name}
    Put String To Cell    ${name}    1    1    90
    Save Excel        ${Path}${name}
```

This gets around your first error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_sheet_index' referenced before assignment

I used `Put Number To Cell` and this caused a

> IndexError: list index out of range

So I used `Put String To Cell` and this now causes a

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\Python27\ExcelRobotTest\Test.xls'

So I think the current code I've posted is your best shot as my work computer as some funny policies stopping me from saving / changing files through Robot... But I am truly stumped :( Ill update more if I manage to get around this issue.

Considering it's complaining about perms - it must have done the writing but cant save.

EDIT1: After switching policy quickly it's now throwing a

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+b') or filename: u'C:\Python27\ExcelRobotTest\Test.xls'

I have no idea what this is...